# How to put text over images in html?

Tags: html

How to put text over images in HTML. Everytime I enter the below code, the text goes under the image.

```
<img src="example.jpg">Text</img>
```

Comment: That is improper HTML; `img` is a self-closing tag, as so: `<img src="example.jpg" alt="Alt text">` (equivalently, in XHTML: `<img src="example.jpg" alt="Alt text" />`).

Answer (score 32):

You can create a div with the exact same size as the image.

```
<div class="imageContainer">Some Text</div>
```

use the css background-image property to show the image

```
 .imageContainer {
       width:200px; 
       height:200px; 
       background-image: url(locationoftheimage);
 }
```

**[more here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-image)**

note: this slichtly tampers the semantics of your document. If needed use javascript to inject the div in the place of a real image.

Answer (score 27):

You need to use absolutely-positioned CSS over a relatively-positioned `img` tag. The article [Text Blocks Over Image](http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/) gives a step-by-step example for placing text over an image.

Comment: Whilst Caspar's solution works perfectly well, I've upvoted this one as it degrades nicely.

Answer (score 19):

The [`<img>` element is empty](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#h-13.2) — it doesn't have an end tag.

If the image is [a background image, use CSS](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/css/properties/background-image/). If it is a content image, then set `position: relative` on a container, then [absolutely position](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning/) the image and/or text within it.

Answer (score 17):

You can try this...

```
<div class="image">

      <img src="" alt="" />

      <h2>Text you want to display over the image</h2>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: `position: absolute;` does the trick, but a killer for responsiveness

Answer (score 5):

Using `absolute` as `position` is not responsive + mobile friendly. I would suggest using a `div` with a `background-image` and then placing text in the `div` will place text over the image. Depending on your html, you might need to use `height` with `vh` value