# How to position text over an image with html?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I center a text over an image with html without css file.I want to do something like the one below but I'm having difficulties and i am using this function also

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function($){    
      $(function(){    
        $("#g1").jFlip(920,539,{background:"green",cornersTop:false}).
        bind("flip.jflip",function(event,index,total){
          $("#l1").html("Image "+(index+1)+" of "+total);
        });
        $("#g2").jFlip(920,539,{background:"green",cornersTop:true,scale:"fit"});
        $("#g3").jFlip(920,539,{background:"green",cornersTop:true,scale:"fill"});
      });
  })(jQuery);
  </script>

    <li>
        <div style="position: relative">
            <div style="top: 12px; left: 12px;">
                <img src="image/banner.jpg" alt="description here"/>
            </div>

            <div style="top: 12px; left: 12px; color: #000;" id="text">
                Place text here
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put text over images in html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758642/how-to-put-text-over-images-in-html)

Comment: Please, if you are already using stackoverflow to ask a question. Search for it on STack first. Because this question is almost asked everyday and set as an duplicate, so you should find an answer when searching.

Comment: @user3506317 Can you explain why you don't want css? It's not that it's seems no big deal for what you're doing.

Comment: you forgot position:absolute; http://jsfiddle.net/5caCQ/ http://jsfiddle.net/5caCQ/ (-1 cause you didn't search)

Comment: @needaname: because text and image also get in database

Answer (score 0):

In your question there's also css. However I have this solution for you :

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zhhzR/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mainContainer">
<img style="position:absolute;" src="http://pamirtimes.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Yasin.jpg" />
    <p style="position:absolute;"> I am Text </p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.