# How to place a nav bar so that it floats on top of an image?

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to place a simple horizontal navigation bar so as that it floats on top (in the bottom left corner
to be precise) of a header. The header is an image of a simple color gradient and is inside of a div. The code
for the nav bar is placed inside of this in another div, but always appears beneath the header. 
Here is the html:

```
<div>
    <img id="Header" src="images/header.jpg"/>
    <div>   
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>  
<img id="Decal" src="images/decal.png"/>
```

And the relavent CSS:

```
#Header {
height:205px;
width: 100%;
z-index:1;
}

#Decal {
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
right: 5px;
top: 1px;
}
#nav {
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 3em 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li {
float: left; }
#nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 8px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #069;
border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li a:hover {
color: #c00;
background-color: #fff; }
```

This has been bugging me for quite awhile so any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HtMNa/

Comment: Sounds like you what want is the image to be a background image?...  If that is the case then remove the `img` tag and apply a css `background:` to the top `div` pointing to the image.

Comment: Is this you are looking for? http://jsbin.com/doyacako/1/edit

Comment: please attach any screenshot how it should be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put text over images in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758642/how-to-put-text-over-images-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, two options here:

1) As @SaganTheBeast said, you can add your image as a `background-image`, and then absolutely position your nav inside of that.

2) You can also do the `position: absolute` trick without moving your image to the background. To do so, you will need to add a wrapper around your HTML, and set `display: relative`. Then, absolutely position your `#nav` element, and add `bottom: 0px` and `width: 100%`. This will pin your `#nav` to the bottom of your container element, and ensure it takes up the full-width.

Here's a working demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWXNQp?editors=1100#0

(Please note, to make it full work as you need, I had to add `margin: 0px` to your existing `#nav` css.)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you put that image as background of the outer div using css:

```
backgroud: url('images/header.jpg')
```

(remember to set the height of this div with the same height of the image)

and then you can position the inner div with position relative or absolute (if you do this you have to set `position: relative` for the outer div)

Answer (score 0):

place the navigation between if you are using bootstrap 5.Make sure to add class="fixed-top" in the div

Comment: Please provide more context wrt. the code provided.

Comment: <div>
    <img id="Header" src="images/header.jpg"/>
    <div class="fixed-top">   
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>  
<img id="Decal" src="images/decal.png"/>