# Text div over image resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wonder if there is any way to put text inside a div over an image, i know can use z-index, but I need the text gets smaller as the size of the image. thanks for everything i want to resizable the textbox with the image

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758642/how-to-put-text-over-images-in-html

Comment: but i want to know if i can resizable the textbox relative to the image

Comment: If you want to resize both of text and img, you can set text and img in div and resize div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way, using viewport units `vw`

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
}
div img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 6vw;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals" alt="">
  <span>Hey there</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

then use relative values for your image(%) and text(em).

Hope it helps.

Comment: You should do a demo (either by pressing CTRL+M in the editor, or via [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ) to demonstrate that your proposed solution will work.

Comment: in a span i can make overflow:scroll?