# I need help adding text on top of an image

Tags: html, css, portfolio

Why is this code not centering my text in the image? I have been working on this for a while, and this is about to drive me crazy. Something so simple is giving trouble.

```css
.header-txt {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5em;
}

.header-wrapper {
    postion: relative;
}

.header-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-wrapper">
    <img class="header-img" src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/website-background-images/website-background-images-20.png" alt="macbook">      
    <div class="header-txt">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe learning some css would help you? Or are you going to build your site just asking questions when ever you don't know what to do?

Comment: He`s right. You can check this website to learn position property: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: @Hardy You really don't think I've been studying CSS already? I understand I need to keep studying CSS. I clearly stated, "I am kind of new to web development." I simply asked for someone to answer my two questions: how to add text over an image, and how to position my "contact" div properly. I have been working on these problems for hours and I am still lost...I'm not asking for someone to bail me out by fixing this problem for me, I'm honestly needing some help. Next time, don't just comment useless information. Thank you, and have a nice day.

Comment: @E.Sawyers sorry for my comment but there is thousands of examples placing text top of an image. That's why i think you haven't even tried to find the solution by your self. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708945/how-to-position-text-over-an-image-in-css

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758642/how-to-put-text-over-images-in-html

+ 1340 more in google..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of really simple things.  First you need to forget the `top:50%`.  When you do this the div is going to start 50% from the top and not center at 50%.  So what you do is add `top:0;` and `bottom:0;`.  Then you need to give your div a height.  What I usually do is if it is not a dynamic height div meaning there is not going to have a lot of text and when resized in responsive design it will stay the same height, then right click on it and inspect the element to see how tall it is then you can give it the height.  So your div is about 90 px tall so add a height of 90 px.  Then set the vertical margin to auto so `margin:auto 0;`  Then it should center the absolute positionded div in the relative positioned div.  So your css will look like so:

```
.header-txt {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;bottom:0;
  margin:auto 0;
  width:100%;
  height:90px;
  font-size:5em;
  text-align:center;
}
.header-wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
.header-img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you are going to have a dynamic height div then you need to use a different technique.  In this technique you will set the top and left percentages.  Most people now are using the css transform property to center div's and it is a very handy technique that now has very good browser support.  Here is the browser support for this technique and it is supported by most browsers now [Transform property broswer support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).  So then your css will look like this:

```
.header-txt {
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size:5em;
}
.header-wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
.header-img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Dont worry about those idiots in the comments above I feel like your question is what this forum is for and some people who frequent the site feel entitled just because they know something that you don't.  I see this in a lot of questions asked on this site anymore and it really drives me crazy.  You obviously tried to figure this out and just have a small question about how to finish this.

Anyway hopefully this helped.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Finally done with the website for now(although I might add a few CSS animations to spice things up). Yea, the comments on my original question were uncalled for.