# Can not place a text over the images in html

Tags: html, css

Can you help me to place a text over every picture "Sign-better.png" in html. I've found some solutions with positions relative and absolute [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758642/how-to-put-text-over-images-in-html), but it doesn't help me because these images are using this thing too.

```
<div style="position: relative">
<img src="rope2.png" class="ropeImageClass" style="z-index: 0;overflow: hidden">
<div style="position: absolute;top: 45%">
    <img src="Sign-better.png" class="my-signs" style="z-index: 1;overflow: hidden;">
    <img src="Sign-better.png" class="my-signs" style="z-index: 1;overflow: hidden;">
    <img src="Sign-better.png" class="my-signs" style="z-index: 1;overflow: hidden;">
</div>
```

This is how it looks:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NvE9.jpg)

[link](https://akrum.github.io/akrum/) to the site prototype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can post the CSS I can be more helpful, but one way you can solve this is to wrap the `<img>` in a `<div>` and then put whatever text you need inside that as a sibling of the `<img>` with `position:absolute` on both the `<img>` and `<p>`. Then they will overlap each other but be constrained to the containing `<div>`, which you would position with whatever CSS you are currently using to position the `<img>`s. You can use `z-index` to sort whether the sign or the text is on top (but in the code I have here, the text would be on top by default).

SO...

```
<div style="position: relative">
<img src="rope2.png" class="ropeImageClass" style="z-index: 0;overflow: hidden">
<div style="position: absolute;top: 45%">
    <div style="position:relative" class="sign-container">
        <img src="Sign-better.png" class="my-signs" style="z-index: 1;overflow: hidden;">
        <p class="sign-text" style="position:absolute;">This is the text for the sign</p>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative" class="sign-container">
        <img src="Sign-better.png" class="my-signs" style="z-index: 1;overflow: hidden;">
        <p class="sign-text" style="position:absolute;">This is the text for the sign</p>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative" class="sign-container">
        <img src="Sign-better.png" class="my-signs" style="z-index: 1;overflow: hidden;">
        <p class="sign-text" style="position:absolute;">This is the text for the sign</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, what should be written in a sign-container class? I can give a [link](https://akrum.github.io/akrum/) to the site prototype. There the whole css can be viewed as wel

Comment: the `sign-container` class would have the position property (I put it in the element style here for clarity, but it should go in the CSS) as well as everything that is in the `my-signs` class. So `sign-container` would handle the sizing and positioning of the whole thing (sign and text). Then just make sure width for `my-sign` is set to 100% and it limit itself to the size of the container.

Comment: Thank you in advance! Your solution has solved the problem