# Text when hovering over images

Tags: html, css

I have created a webpage with three images in a row each taking up four columns I want to have different text appear over the different images when the mouse is hovered over them. I would appreciate help with this.

My current HTML code is as follows:

```css
.col-4 {width: 33.33%; float:left;}
.col-4 img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;   
}
```

```html
<div class= "container">
  <div class= "overPhotos">
    <div class= "row">
      <div class="col-4 ">
        <img src="rick_sanchez.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 ">
        <img src="morty_smith.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="summer_smith.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try doing a search for this before posting? There are literally [hundreds of similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=text+hover+over+image) with answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put text over images in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758642/how-to-put-text-over-images-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `:hover` block to whatever element you want to hover over. This is the code that will achieve this for you:

```
.col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.col-4 img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
}

.col-4 .hover-text {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 100;
}

.col-4:hover > .hover-text {
  display: block;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="overPhotos">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 ">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-640-480-1.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <span class="hover-text">Hello, World!</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 ">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-640-480-1.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <span class="hover-text">Hello, World!</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-640-480-1.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <span class="hover-text">Hello, World!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added `position: absolute;` to each hover element, which necessitated adding a `position: relative;` to each container.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kkvk1wua/1/).

Answer (score 1):

The basic way of doing this is with the title attribute:

```
<img src="" alt="" title="your text goes here">
```

Or maybe something more advanced: [Link](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/index3.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try following simple style.

```css
.col-4 {width: 33.33%; float:left;position: relative;overflow: hidden;}
.col-4 img{
width: 100%;
max-width: 300px;
height: 150px;
display: inline-block;   
}

.col-4 .caption {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 4px;
  bottom: -100%;
  transition: bottom ease 0.4s;
}

.col-4:hover .caption {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class= "container">

<div class= "overPhotos">
    <div class= "row">
        <div class="col-4 ">
        <img src="rick_sanchez.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="caption">Image 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 ">
        <img src="morty_smith.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="caption">Image 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
        <img src="summer_smith.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="caption">Image 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.col-4 {width: 30%; float:left; background: #000; margin: 10px; position: relative;}
.col-4 img{
width: 100%;
max-width: 300px;
height: 300px;
display: inline-block;   
}
.col-4 span {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    display:none;
}
.col-4:hover span  {
display:block;
}
```

```html
   <div class= "container">

<div class= "overPhotos">
    <div class= "row">
        <div class="col-4 ">
        <img src="rick_sanchez.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <span>image caption</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 ">
        <img src="morty_smith.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
         <span>image caption</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
        <img src="summer_smith.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
         <span>image caption</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```css
.col-4 {width: 30%; float:left; background: #000; margin: 10px; position: relative;}
.col-4 img{
width: 100%;
max-width: 300px;
height: 300px;
display: inline-block;   
}
.col-4 span {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
   <div class= "container">

<div class= "overPhotos">
    <div class= "row">
        <div class="col-4 ">
        <img src="rick_sanchez.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <span>image caption</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 ">
        <img src="morty_smith.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
         <span>image caption</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
        <img src="summer_smith.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
         <span>image caption</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This shows the text over the image but the OP wanted the text to appear on hover.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add title attribute in the image tag...

```
<img src="rick_sanchez.png" title="abc"  alt="Avatar" class="image">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the alt text on your images.

`<img src="summer_smith.png" alt="<your text here>" class="image">`

Comment: You probably mean the title attribute.

Comment: I see that it has changed, it used to be alt. Been away from html to long i guess.

Answer (score 0):

How about this CSS only approach?

```
.col-4:nth-child(1):hover:after{position: absolute; content:"your text 1";}
.col-4:nth-child(2):hover:after{position: absolute; content:"your text 2";}
.col-4:nth-child(3):hover:after{position: absolute; content:"your text 3";}
```

Check these cute kittens for a working demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZgQPE

*PS. Please Ctrl-click the link as [SO refuses to implement target='_blank'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313734/how-to-add-target-blank-to-a-hyperlink-on-an-answer).*