# how to place text over an <input type = "image" /> element?

Tags: html, css

I can not write on over, I tried in several ways, but it still did not work, how do I do it? 
I believe this is different because it is **`<input type="image">`** and not **`<img>`** !
**I want position the text on the image at the bottom**

---

```css
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered ">Example
  <input type="image" id="MY_ID" src="img.png" class="btTxt submit " width="100" height="130" />
</div>
```

Comment: can you define `write over an ..` ?

Comment: so, you want to make it type "text" when you click on it?

Comment: write a text on over... as if it were an image element.

Comment: "_write a text on over_" It is not clear what this means.

Comment: @Cheshire,no, just put a text via html and css.

Comment: I'm going to edit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put text over images in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758642/how-to-put-text-over-images-in-html)

Comment: you could likely use a label element and position is relative and adjust the left and top property so it appears over the image.

Comment: @floor,just stay on the side, and not Over an <input type = "image">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try put an image on the input itself, use a wrapping div and add the image to that.

HTML

```
<div class="inputbutton">
  <span class="text">Hello World!</span>
  <input type="submit" class="btTxt submit" name="" value="">
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.inputbutton {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.inputbutton input {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/200x100') no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
}

span.text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/msyhoaak/18/

Comment: that way I can not position the text on the image at the bottom