# Adding Integrated Text/Image CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I would like to make a homepage image like the attachments ( since I do not have enough point/reputation, stackoverflow won't let me share as a image instead it's a link ). Even though I have made lots of research I could not find any answers nor I can't think any way to achieve this. Basically, I would like to integrate texts letter with an image. I would like to write the text in HTML. Is there any way you can help me?

Thanks much.
Best,
Nathan.

[Integrated Text/Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9n62.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put text over images in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758642/how-to-put-text-over-images-in-html)

Comment: You are not putting text over or behind an image in a strict sense but layering the text within the image.  SVG may allow you to do this however this is not going to be easy - it might be better just to create the set of images you need with embedded text.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Ah, you're correct Mark. SVG is a good solution, I guess. Unfortunately, I'm not very intimate with SVG and as you mentioned it is should be hard. So, I guess I just use Photoshop and implement the desired image. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is here

```
    <div class="dark">
   <h1>Chicago</h1>
  <img src="yourimage" alt="Photograph of the Chicago skyline taken from the water during the day">
</div>

<div class="light">
   <h1>Houston</h1>
  <img src="yourimage" alt="Photograph of the Houston skyline taken from a tree-lined park">
</div>

    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700);
body { 
  margin: 0;
}
div { 
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
div h1 { 
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20vw; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.9;
}
.dark h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
.light h1 {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 19vw;
}
div img { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;  
}
.dark {
  background: #000;
}
.light {
  background: #fff;
}
.dark img {
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}
.light img {
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jigar. But that's not actually what I want. As you can see in the image ( that I shared ), some of the letters go behind of the image and some of them in front of the image. I would like to achieve that.

Comment: Well, I don't have any code yet. My client would like to see this design on its website. So right now it is just a concept.

Answer (score 0):

My slightly opinionated answer:
You are not putting text over or behind an image in a strict sense but layering the text within the image.

1. SVG may allow you to do this however this is not going to be easy.
2. It might be better just to create the set of images you need with
   embedded text.
3. Combine images and text (html) in a set of layers, transparent images, text, another image etc.  The CSS on this is likely to be pretty complicated with the need to "stack" the layers properly, create multiple images to display in that stack. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context  Related z-index with stacking https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, Mark. I guess the second option is the best. Better to avoid using stacking layers ( the third option ) since handling the device width is going to be too complex. On mobile devices, it should be hard to maintain positions. Thank you so much tho.