# How do I make p appear on hover ONTOP of an image?

Tags: html, css

I know the question of overlapping has been answered multiple times, however, I'm trying to place the text on top of the image centred once hovered. 
I tried z-index, I tried relative and absolute, decided I'd ask for help.

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 7%;
    padding-right: 7%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    justify-content: center;

}
.flex-container div {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 0;
}

.flex-container div:hover {
    filter: brightness(50%);
}

.flex-container div p {
    display: none;
}

.flex-container div:hover p {
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="Printing/menus.html">
        <img src="../Images/menus-01.png" alt="Printing" style="width:100%; height:auto;"/>
    </a>
    <p>Menus</p>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no element with .flex-container in your HTML? You need to set the parent div to position relative then set position absolute on the p element you want to overlap. You :hover event should only display:block for the child p element.

Comment: Where is the `.flex-container` element in your HTML?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add it to the code. I have made the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have set the text CSS first and just then get the hover to show the styles, also, you forgot to set the container styles on your code.

See if that's what you want :

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="../Images/menus-01.png" alt="Image" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="topTxt">Text on Center/div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.topTxt {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}

.container:hover .topTxt {
  display: block;
}
```

**OR** use JavaScript :

```
document.getElementsByClass("container").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  document.getElementsByClass("topTxt").style.display = "block";
});
```

Get the following snippet to better view of what you requested :

```css
#container {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
}

#container li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container-cells {
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imgs {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  filter: brightness(100%);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#container li:hover .imgs {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #000;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#container li:hover .overlay {
  height: 30px;
}

.title {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  transition: all .3s;
}

#container li:hover .title {
  transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 0.9;
}

@media (max-width: 9000px) {
  #container li {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  #container li {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  #container li {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="container">
  <li>
    <a class="container-cells" href="#">
      <img class="imgs" src="https://www.madpaws.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Raise-Your-Kitten-to-Use-the-Litter-Box-300x200.jpg">
      <span class="overlay"></span>
      <span class="title">Hello World !</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="container-cells" href="#">
      <img class="imgs" src="https://www.madpaws.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Raise-Your-Kitten-to-Use-the-Litter-Box-300x200.jpg">
      <span class="overlay"></span>
      <span class="title">Hello World !</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="container-cells" href="#">
      <img class="imgs" src="https://www.madpaws.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Raise-Your-Kitten-to-Use-the-Litter-Box-300x200.jpg">
      <span class="overlay"></span>
      <span class="title">Hello World !</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="container-cells" href="#">
      <img class="imgs" src="https://www.madpaws.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Raise-Your-Kitten-to-Use-the-Litter-Box-300x200.jpg">
      <span class="overlay"></span>
      <span class="title">Hello World !</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="container-cells" href="#">
      <img class="imgs" src="https://www.madpaws.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Raise-Your-Kitten-to-Use-the-Litter-Box-300x200.jpg">
      <span class="overlay"></span>
      <span class="title">Hello World !</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="container-cells" href="#">
      <img class="imgs" src="https://www.madpaws.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Raise-Your-Kitten-to-Use-the-Litter-Box-300x200.jpg">
      <span class="overlay"></span>
      <span class="title">Hello World !</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="container-cells" href="#">
      <img class="imgs" src="https://www.madpaws.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Raise-Your-Kitten-to-Use-the-Litter-Box-300x200.jpg">
      <span class="overlay"></span>
      <span class="title">Hello World !</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="container-cells" href="#">
      <img class="imgs" src="https://www.madpaws.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Raise-Your-Kitten-to-Use-the-Litter-Box-300x200.jpg">
      <span class="overlay"></span>
      <span class="title">Hello World !</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="container-cells" href="#">
      <img class="imgs" src="https://www.madpaws.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Raise-Your-Kitten-to-Use-the-Litter-Box-300x200.jpg">
      <span class="overlay"></span>
      <span class="title">Hello World !</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You just need to put the text before the image, as the image will be the background either way, just add the the text before, then the image and the text will be siblings, not parent and child, so the effect of hover won't affect the child, therefore, the text color will remain without having the filter applied to it.

Comment: Still appears below

Comment: My apologies, it works indeed. I had placed the relative property on the .container div. I had a question though. I have ```filter: brightness(50%)``` on hover as well. So it turns the white to grey. Is there a way to keep the .topTxt white? I tried ```z-index: 1;```

Comment: Try changing from `filter` to `opacity` on your style, so when hovering change to `opacity: 0.5;`.

Comment: Remember that you can also include a JS `addEventListener` to make this change and apply it using the `style.opacity = "0.5"`

Comment: I'd prefer to darken than fade out. But in regards to the opacity, wouldn't that be applied to the text as well? Because it's under ```.flex-container div``` ? I still haven't learned any javascript, but if there's something to solve this problem, I'd greatly appreciate if you could help me

Comment: Edited the answer, see if that's what you're looking for

Comment: The problem with this is the container I use is for multiple images in a grid layout. What this does is as soon as I move the mouse into the container of all images, the text appears. Is there a workaround on that?

Comment: Edited again the whole Snippet so now that you said it's in a grid, added a container and made the grid using `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. See the code and tell me if that's what you were willing to happen

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the below is what you're looking for?

[How to put text over images in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758642/how-to-put-text-over-images-in-html)

The answer suggests using a "div" tag rather than an "img" tag. Here is an example:

```css
 .image {
       width:400px; 
       height:400px; 
       background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-4.jpg);
       background-size:cover;
 }
```

```html
<div class="image">Text on top of image</div>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, you should put the relevant code here or this could have been a comment. You can also flag the question as a potential duplicate.

Comment: I want it to be fluid, so i tried replacing the px to %, then it used 100% of the text, not of the image

Comment: If you want to use percentages for div's, you'll need to add "position:absolute" to the css.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It's wider than the text now, but the height of the text with height set to auto