# How to make a text on an image selectable when rendered in an html page if I have the text present on that image?

Tags: html, tesseract

I have an image of a scanned document with text, and I managed to extract text from that image using Tesseract. But now I want to render this image on a webpage making it possible to select the text written on the document.
One approach I had in mind was to create a layer of text on top of the image and render text over the image canvas, but I don't really know how to make this possible.

Comment: https://ishank-dev.github.io/Image-Text-Selector/ 
This is the link for the demo, just add the URL of an image with text on it, for example, a book page. If somehow the generated text could come over the top of the image the problem will be solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve the problem, the book pages I was trying to select text from, had an XML file for all the book pages, which contains the coordinates for each line and words. So all I did was pass the coordinates of a selected rectangular region, checked if the words are lying within that region and printed them. You can see the demo [here](http://ishank-dev.github.io/Image-Text-Selector)

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty examples for this on internet e.g.

- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp
- [How to put text over images in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758642/how-to-put-text-over-images-in-html)
- https://pavenum.com/en/images-and-text-overlays-in-html-css

Tricky would be align position of recognized words to image position.

Comment: Yes, alignment is the main issue here. It will only work if we have the image in the same format as that of the extracted words.